# Loading local json file into redux store with axios, but it fails after I refresh in another route

Tags: json, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

So I'm practicing React and Redux, and I'm loading a local json file into the store like this ...

```
import { LOAD_BOOKS } from "./booksConstants";
import axios from "axios";

export const loadBooks = data => {
    return {
        type: LOAD_BOOKS,
        payload: data
    };
};

export const asyncLoadBooks = () => {
    return async dispatch => {
        const response = await axios.get("books.json");
        const data = response.data.books;
        dispatch(loadBooks(data));
    };
};
```

And here's the reducer ...

```
import { LOAD_BOOKS } from "./booksConstants";
import { createReducer } from "../../store/reducerUtil";

const initialState = {
    books: []
};

export const loadBooks = (state, payload) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        books: payload
    };
};

export default createReducer(initialState, {
    [LOAD_BOOKS]: loadBooks
});
```

And I'm connecting the App.js to the store with connect() and firing the 'asyncLoadBooks()' in 'componentDidMount()' like this ...

```
componentDidMount() {
    try {
        this.props.asyncLoadBooks();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

And everything is working just fine when I loop over the data and display them, however, if I'm on any other route other than "/" and refresh the app manually it gives me this error `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I tried to move the methods to the constructor instead of 'componentDidMount' but it didn't work.

What should I do here? And please keep in mind that I want to use axios and redux to practice them.

## Edit

I put a console.log into each async action creator and apparently when I'm on any route other than the home "/" it tries to get the JSON file from this path and can't find it `GET http://localhost:3000/category/books.json 404 (Not Found)`

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you use Route component?

Comment: I think you're going to need to provide the relative path to `books.json`.

Comment: @HenokTesfaye I do use <Route> yes, and it's working just fine, it's only when I refresh in another route other than the "/".

Comment: @Colin I tried that, but it didn't work, I have the `books.json` file inside the `/public` folder, that's the only way to get it to work, I searched for it.

Comment: Can u post the code that shows about routing?

Comment: @HenokTesfaye Here's the render method of the `App.js` ...

`render() {
 return (
  <>
   <Header />
   <div className="global-wrapper">
    <div className="container">
     <aside className="side-bar">
      <Categories />
     </aside>

     <main className="main-content">
      <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/" component={Books} />
       <Route
        path="/category/:id"
        component={Category}
       />
       <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
     </main>
    </div>
   </div>
  </>
 );
}`

Comment: @HenokTesfaye @Colin I think I narrowed down the issue, I put a console.log in each async action creator, and the one for the categories didn't fire, and gave me the error that apparently it tries to load the json file from this path and can't find it `http://localhost:3000/category/books.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, guys, I figured it out, the problem was in `axios` trying to the fetch the JSON file from different paths when you're on different routes, I fixed that by setting a global default baseURL for axios in the `index.js` file like this ...

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.baseURL = "http://localhost:3000/";
```

And now you can refresh in any route and the data will be fetched successfully.